# Convergence of a sequence with order of convergence $ > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

If $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1} \subset \mathbb{R}, x_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}x^*$ with order of convergence $r > 1$, then $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 0} \subset \mathbb{R}$ converges to $x^*$ with superliniar convergence rate.

My proof:
Because $x_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty}x^*$ with order of convergence $r > 1$ we have that $\exists c > 0$ s.t. $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{|x^*-x_n|}{|x^*-x_{n-1}|^r} = c$. So, we have that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{|x^*-x_n|}{|x^*-x_{n-1}|} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{|x^*-x_n|}{|x^*-x_{n-1}|^r} \cdot |x^*-x_{n-1}|^{r-1} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{|x^*-x_n|}{|x^*-x_{n-1}|^r} \cdot \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}|x^*-x_{n-1}|^{r-1} = c \cdot 0 = 0$

So, we have that $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ converges to $x^*$ with superliniar convergence rate.

My question: Is this proof ok? And if it's ok... how influence $n \geq 1$ or $n \geq 0$ the order of convergence and the rate of convergence? Because I don't understand why we first have $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and need to proof for $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 0}$. Why we don't prove for $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ ?

Comment: Your last question is just a carelessness. In question of convergence, the first 10, or 100  or even 1000 elements do not matter. The limits are also correct.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So for any convergent sequence with order of convergence $r>1$ we have that that sequence also have superliniar convege rate? (reciprocal is not true)

Comment: Yes. A well-known example is the secant method. If the function is smooth enough and the sequence convergent, then you get a superlinear convergence order of $r=\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$.